# Loading tau-prolog.js-packages in runtime?

Tags: prolog, tau-prolog

I am making an online-IDE for Prolog, using tau-prolog, and I need to be able to import external tau-prolog module-packages in js-form, so I can use the predicates in already defined modules.

I'm having a bit of trouble with this, and I am getting confusing behaviour.

Is there any recommended way of doing this?

For now, I am getting the js-packages as text, through AJAX, and then doing eval on them to bring that js-code into memory (yes, I know eval has downsides, but for starters I'm trying this method). -Sometimes it works fine, and other times not, which is why I'm reaching out like this :-)